# Apps that are Chromium or Electron base crashes on Catalina beta 6 (19A536g)

Tags: applications, crash, beta-seed-program, catalina, beta

So I recently updated from beta 5 of Catalina to beta 6 and noticed more than half of my apps will crash after the initial launch, these apps include things like:

- Brave browser (beta, nightly)
- Chrome (tried beta as well)
- Chrome Canary (the same)

Any apps that are electronJS based such as: Spotify, Slack, Atom, VSCode & etc...

I have a hunch that it has something to do with a browser wrapper that can't be set

Already tried and failed:
`sudo spctl --master-disable`

Also re-installed apps, tried a whole different version and to no avail

is there anything I can do to fix this locally?

Comment: The OS is still in beta so you should expect some applications to not work.  Did you file a Feedback with Apple about this problem?  Also, I don't see any question in your question.   You might want to edit this to bring your question forward a little more.

Comment: Hey @fsb and thanks for your comment, edited the question to make it more like a question :) also yes, I expect to not having apps to work but it was working on beta 5 and after updating to beta 6 more than 70% of the apps stopped working, that's not expected IMO

Comment: It's a beta, things can get better *or* worse with each release. Provide feedback to Apple and the various software providers and move on :-)

Comment: So I ended up, wipe cleaning everything and getting back to Mojave ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @nohillside Things got slightly better in beta 7, but the issue is still not resolved. :\

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the best you can do is revert to Mojave. This is a bug in AppKit that Apple caused (and must soon fix). It persists in beta 7.

I can feel your pain. I need my Electron apps like VS Code and Insomnia. The bug also affects JetBrains apps like PyCharm and Android Studio (based off IntelliJ).